# Pickle and Glue jobs

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pickle, aws-glue

Suppose you have a glue job on AWS with the following python script:

```
import pickle
results = [1,2,3]
with open('results.pkl', 'w') as f: 
    pickle.dump(results_all, f)
```

Would this work? If so, where would the results.pkl file go?